# How to create nested tables with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display JSON response data in a table. Schema is not known in advance and JSON can contain at most one nested object.
This example shows a table, which displays key-value pairs:

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    a: 42,
    b: "test",
    c: {
      x: -1,
      y: 1
    }
  };

  $scope.getTypeOf = function(obj) {
    return typeof obj;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="" ng-controller="TestController" border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td ng-switch on="getTypeOf(value)">
      <div ng-switch-when="object">
        obj: {{value}}
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-default>{{value}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, for the property "c", I want to create a nested table like this:

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    a: 42,
    b: "test",
    c: {
      x: -1,
      y: 1
    }
  };

  $scope.getTypeOf = function(obj) {
    return typeof obj;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="" ng-controller="TestController" border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td ng-switch on="getTypeOf(value)">
      <div ng-switch-when="object">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
          <td>{{key1}}</td>
          <td>{{value1}}</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-default>{{value}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Intuitively this should work, but it throws [Error: $compile:ctreq Missing Required Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngSwitch&p1=ngSwitchDefault) in Chrome. How can I achieve correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    a: 42,
    b: "test",
    c: {
      x: -1,
      y: 1
    }
  };

  $scope.getTypeOf = function(obj) {

    return typeof obj;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="" ng-controller="TestController" border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td ng-switch on="getTypeOf(value)">
      <table ng-switch-when="object"  border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
          <td >{{key1}}</td>
          <td >{{value1}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div ng-switch-default>{{value}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i update my answer. please if it is correct accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined your controller is wrong.

You need something like

```
angular.module('app').controller("TestController", ['$scope', 
  function($scope){ 
    // your controller code 
  }
]);
```

Comment: I only simplified it for this question.

Answer (score 0):

the `value` on `ng-switch-when="object"` is an object to array. you need to use `Object.keys` to extract the object keys, and then you can read each one of them and build your `key` `value` table

Comment: Something like `ng-repeat="key1 in Object.keys(value)"`? It throws the same error.